# in MySQL what is the query to show these student's that each marks less than 50?

Tags: mysql, mysql-5.5, mysql-5.6, mysql-5.7

I have this table marks in MySQL database

[image]

I used a query to output this table that shown as below:

it's my output:

[image]

I want use a query to show these student's that each marks less than 50,
output for example above only Liza and Jake with marks appear

What is the MySQL query for do this work? how i can?

Comment: *and Jake* Why? Jake gets 80 for Access, it is not "less than 50"...

Comment: @Akina _Jake_ is less than mark in two other subject.

Comment: ??? Maybe you want not "each marks", but "at least one of the marks"?

Comment: @Akina, each one of them less than 50, must be this row appear.

Comment: That is, when all 3 columns show less than 50, output the row.  So Liza should appear _but not Jake_.  Perhaps you mean "If _any_ mark is below 50, display the row"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
SELECT Name, 
       MAX(CASE WHEN Subject = 'Word' then Marks END) Word,
       MAX(CASE WHEN Subject = 'Excel' then Marks END) Excel,
       MAX(CASE WHEN Subject = 'Access' then Marks END) Access
FROM Datatable
GROUP BY Name
    -- If ALL marks must be below 50
-- HAVING GREATEST(Word, Excel, Access) < 50;
    -- If at least one mark must be below 50
HAVING LEAST(Word, Excel, Access) < 50;
```

Comment: would be `LEAST` to show students with any below 50 score.

Comment: I see ***each** marks less than 50*, not any...

Comment: There is a difference between exact wording and sample provided. Nice solution regardless.